# What type of collection do ListViews use to store their data?

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, data-structures, dataset

I just need to know what kind of collection a listview uses to store its data. I see in the documentation that it's its own special kind of collection (ListViewItemCollection) but, is this an offshoot of another kind of collection or is it unique to ListViews entirely?

Comment: Post some sample code to improve your question. Have a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question.

Comment: @lloydm What sort of sample code would I post? The question is not code specific but a cut-and-dry answer.

Comment: Could you please clarify what part of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx you need explanation about?

Comment: @UpAllNight It would help if you show what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `ListViewItemCollection` is defined as an inner class of `ListView`.

The signature looks like this:

```
public class ListViewItemCollection : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
{
    ...
}
```

Internally it uses a `ListView.ListViewItemCollection.IInnerList` to hold the actual elements, and in implemented by `ListViewNativeItemCollection`.

This has the following signature:

```
internal class ListViewNativeItemCollection : ListViewItemCollection.IInnerList
{
    ...
}
```

`IInnerList` looks like this:

```
internal interface IInnerList
{
    int Count { get; }
    bool OwnerIsVirtualListView { get; }
    bool OwnerIsDesignMode{ get; }
    ListViewItem this[int index] { get; set; }
    ListViewItem Add(ListViewItem item);
    void AddRange(ListViewItem[] items);
    void Clear();
    bool Contains(ListViewItem item);
    void CopyTo(Array dest, int index);
    IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
    int IndexOf(ListViewItem item);
    ListViewItem Insert(int index, ListViewItem item);
    void Remove(ListViewItem item);
    void RemoveAt(int index);
}
```

Looks like this is all pre-generics days.